# Find and move files that are NOT in a text list Linux

Tags: mysql, linux, redhat

I am cleaning up the storage of an old database and need to remove all of the files that are currently not in use.

I have a list of the files and paths that are active and would like to move all of the files that are not active into a single location where I can review and then delete them if not needed.

I am running mySQL 5.0 on RHEL5

How can I use xargs or find to locate the paths/files that are not on activefiles.txt

All help is much appreciated. Thank you.

UPDATED BELOW:

Let me try and be more clear. I have a mysql database which contains the path and filename in one of the tables.

```
mysql> select FilePath from metadata;
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| FilePath                                              |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| ./sample/XYZ/filename1 |
| ./sample/XYZ/filename2 |
| ./sample/XYZ/filename3 |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What I need to do is place this column into a text document and then remove all the subdirectories and files in directory XYZ that are NOT on this list.

For example:

```
$mysql -u root -e ‘select FilePath from database.metadata;’  > deletelist.txt
$xargs rm > deletelist.txt
```

This would remove all of the files returned from the mysql query.

What I want to do is remove all of the files in the same subdirectory that are NOT in deletelist.txt

Hope thats a little more clear

Comment: Please post the format of the list (some example lines would be enough) otherwise it is close to impossible to give a proper answer.

Comment: Where is the connection between files and mysql here?

Comment: To be even more specific and safe, I would like to move all of the files first and then delete them.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be:  create a temporary folder to hold the files you want and move them there.  Then move the remaining files in the folder somewhere else, move the original files back, and delete the unwanted files.  This way you never have to enumerate the unwanted files (you can let the shell do it).

Note that in most filesystems, moving files is cheap - it doesn't require copying the bits, just updating directories.

Comment: The issue is that these files are actively being used and moving them would break production. I need them to stay where they are and delete everything around them.  I should also note that I am dealing with over 1M files.

Comment: how about setting them to read-only and then using find to remove everything that is writable?

Comment: alternatively, you could list all the files into some file and then get the lines in that file that are *not* in your other list (using the comm command, say), and then use xargs.  Be careful about new files that get created while you are running though.  You might want to add an additional check on created time...

Comment: The read/write option could be useful, but I would rather not touch the active files at all. Listing all the files and comm'ing the two may be a good way to go. But I am very curious if there is a simpler way just using xargs or a combination of find and xargs that would be faster.

Comment: I recall using something like  "$find /XYZ type -f \( -path ./123 \) -prune" This would find all files in /XYZ excluding anything in subdirectory /123. If there is a way to pass a file in this command then that could work as well.

Comment: I don't think find has an exclude arg.  You could write it yourself in perl or python, but IMO the comm thing is the best I know how with existing commands.  I don't think speed should be a concern there, either.